# Elements overflow container when scrollbars appear

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm building a site layout ( should be cross-browser ie7,8,9 and all the recent ones ) and everything was great until i tried to zoom in. When the scrollbars appear, the header's floated elements move out of its container ( so it seems ).

Currently the behaviour persists on every browser, and also the page is using a sticky footer so i can't really modify the main structure i guess.

Here is the page:
http://www.mindsinfusion.com/k/

Any ideas on how to fix this? Am i doing something terribly wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #pageHeader & footer DIV's are defined for 100% width, which applies to the window.   when you zoom, you're window effectively is getting smaller.

I tried adding a `min-width: 1030px;` to your css and it worked, in chrome & firefox, but it may not be fully cross-browser solution.

Comment: That worked like a charm m8, and works in all ie's. Thanks :-)